# ASP:DynamicControl rendering HTML rather then displaying source

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have a ASP dynamic scaffolding project in which I am customizing a details view. In my data source I have a few fields containing HTML and I would like to display the rendered HTML on the page rather then the source HTML as it is currently doing. The control looks like this.

```
<tr>
  <td class="DDLightHeader">
     <asp:Label ID="lblStatementHtml" runat="server" Text="Statement" />
  </td>
  <td>
     <asp:DynamicControl ID="dcStatementHtml" runat="server" DataField="StatementHtml"  />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am confused on how to proceed since the default view for this control is the Text.ascx which is apparently nothing more then a literal (the same base control I use to render the HTML on my site. I am comfortable with creating a new FieldTemplate to render the HTML, but how can I force the html to render rather then display its source view.

Comment: are you sure its a dynamic control that you should be using? Maybe consider a Response.Write to a declared area of the page. The write will insert the html, so it should render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the above issue I had to create  anew FieldTemplate

HTML.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="HTML.ascx.cs" Inherits="ProductDynamicCMS.HTML" %>

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" />
```

HTML.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace ProductDynamicCMS
{
    public partial class HTML : FieldTemplateUserControl
    {
        protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDataBinding(e);

            object val = FieldValue;
            if (val != null)
                Literal1.Text = val.ToString();
        }

        public override Control DataControl
        {
            get
            {
                return Literal1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then applied the UIHint for this class to the field display in the details view template.

```
<tr>
  <td class="DDLightHeader">
     <asp:Label ID="lblStatementHtml" runat="server" Text="Statement" />
  </td>
  <td>
     <asp:DynamicControl ID="dcStatementHtml" runat="server" DataField="StatementHtml" UIHint="HTML"  />
  </td>
</tr>
```

And all was well.